# Merge List of lists where sublists have common elements

Tags: python, list, merge

I have a list of lists like this

```
list = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [4, 5]]
```

and as you see the first element of the first two sublists is repeated

So I want my output too be:

```
list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should solve your problem:

```
def merge_subs(lst_of_lsts):
    res = []
    for row in lst_of_lsts:
        for i, resrow in enumerate(res):
            if row[0]==resrow[0]:
                res[i] += row[1:]
                break
        else:
            res.append(row)
    return res
```

Note that the `else`belongs to the inner `for` and is executed if the loop is exited without hitting the break.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution that builds a dict first with the 1st values, then creates a list from that, but the order may not be the same (i.e. `[4, 5]` may be before `[1, 2, 3]`):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> map(lambda x: d[x[0]].append(x[1]), l)
[None, None, None]
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [2, 3], 4: [5]})
>>> [[key] + list(val) for key, val in d.iteritems()]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Although arguably unreadable:

```
# Note the _ after the list, otherwise you are redefining the list type in your scope
list_ = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [4, 5]]

from itertools import groupby
grouper = lambda l: [[k] + sum((v[1::] for v in vs), []) for k, vs in groupby(l, lambda x: x[0])]

print grouper(list_)
```

A more readable variant:

```
from collections import defaultdict
groups = defaultdict(list)
for vs in list_:
    group[vs[0]] += vs[1:]

print group.items()
```

Note that these solve a more generic form of your problem, instead of `[[1, 2], [1, 3], [4, 5]]` you could also have something like this: `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 5], [2, 4, 5, 6], [3]]`

---

Explanation about the `_`. This is why you don't want to overwrite `list`:

```
spam = list()
print spam
# returns []

list = spam
print list
# returns []

spam = list()
# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

As you can see above, by setting `list = spam` we broke the default behaviour of `list()`.

Comment: @user1422056: the _ suffix is the default convention to prevent name clashes with other variables. Since `list` already exists in Python, it is common to use `list_` instead. The same goes for `del`, `with`, `for`, and more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python sets, because you can compute intersection and union pretty easy. The code would be more clear, but the complexity would probably be comparable to the other solutions.